# What is the behavior if a spam question is edited to a meaningful question

Tags: discussion, edits, spam

Here is the scenario I have in mind:

1. A question is posted on Stack Overflow.
2. Apparently, it is spam (like test questions, eqruiosdsadsldfjdsd)
3. Someone flagged it is spam.
4. Question is edited, and spam content is removed.

What will happen to following?

1. Question: will it be deleted? (It was spam at the time of reporting)
2. If the question is not deleted, how the flag will look like in the flag history page?

   > [image]

   (Declined or disputed or deemed helpful)
3. Is there a way to revert the flag if once spam is indicated for such scenarios?

Comment: Sadly flags can't be retracted. How often does this come uo however? Spammers usually only want to spam

Comment: Incidentally; it may be useful to link to a particular post you think qualifies here.

Comment: I flagged [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777815/just-a-test-will-remove-asap) as spam. It is currently deleted. What would have happened if before deletion, it was *edited* to legit post.

Comment: @tilak that's not spam, by the way. I deleted it due to another flag which pointed out it wasn't a question, but just a 'test'. It was not at all correct to flag that as spam.

Answer (score 14):

If a post truly was spam, there's no way it can be edited into a legitimate post.

Said another way; if a post can be edited into a legitimate post, it should not have been flagged as spam.

Spam flags are for posts that serve *no purpose* other than to advertise a product. You note in an above comment that you flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777815/just-a-test-will-remove-asap) as Spam (10k+ only). That post is *not spam at all*, so that flag was not valid to begin with.

---

If someone edited a true spam post into a valid question somehow, then they are significantly (totally) changing the meaning of the post, and that would be an invalid edit to begin with.

Comment: At different times. At one point of time, a spam. At other point of time a legit post.

Comment: @Tilak Again; if a post truly was spam at one time, there's *no way* it could be edited into a legitimate post. Most likely, the post was not spam in the first place.

Comment: Sometimes a question looks like a cover for spam, what if its edited to remove the spam, leaving just the cover (which is probably a poor but valid question)

Comment: @Richard that makes it harder to identify spam, but such questions tend to be legetimate questions though bad one). Such questions should be edited, and not flagged as spam. Maybe an "other" flag explaining one's suspicions, but Spam flags should only be for obvious, plain old spam.

Comment: This is the only possible answer. Nobody should ever edit true spam into something useful, ever. That doesn't make any sense. The only thing that can and should happen to spam is burnination